# How can I Select the values from different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In an example below, how will I implement a sql query that selects from different tables.

```
SalesCodeA
----------------------------------------------------
ID | EMPLOYEE NAME | EMPLOYEE CODE || EMPLOYEE SALES
1     STEVE JOBS          A               1000

SalesCodeB
----------------------------------------------------
ID | EMPLOYEE NAME | EMPLOYEE CODE || EMPLOYEE SALES
1     BILL GATES          B               2000

SalesCodeC
----------------------------------------------------
ID | EMPLOYEE NAME | EMPLOYEE CODE || EMPLOYEE SALES
1     JOHN APPLE          C               3000
```

How will I implement something that will get the data based on the EmployeeCode?? i tried using

```
 SELECT * FROM SalesCodeA, SalesCodeB, SalesCodeC WHERE EmployeeCode ="A";
```

but it's not working.

Comment: `UNION` the tables

Comment: Wrong approach. Have one single table for all Salecodes.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for this(`UNION ALL`)

```
SELECT ID,[EMPLOYEE NAME],[EMPLOYEE CODE],[EMPLOYEE SALES]
FROM   TABLE_1
WHERE  [EMPLOYEE CODE] = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,[EMPLOYEE NAME],[EMPLOYEE CODE],[EMPLOYEE SALES]
FROM   TABLE_2
WHERE  [EMPLOYEE CODE] = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,[EMPLOYEE NAME],[EMPLOYEE CODE],[EMPLOYEE SALES]
FROM   TABLE_3
WHERE  [EMPLOYEE CODE] = 'A'
```

Also having individual table for each employee doesn't look like a proper design, have single table for all the employee since `employee code` or `employee ID` are going to be unique

Answer (score 0):

I understand your query completely but  I can suggest you to use union from the different queries as all table structure are same.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE EMP_CODE='A';
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE_2 WHERE EMP_CODE='B';
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE_3 WHERE EMP_COE='C';
```

Comment: Format the query and use UNION ALL to select all the records UNION will select only unique records from all the tables but requirement is to select all the data from all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM SalesCodeA UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM SalesCodeB UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM SalesCodeC) t WHERE t.EmployeeCode ="A";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` operator. Make sure all the tables having same number of columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT * FROM SalesCodeA 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM SalesCodeB 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM SalesCodeC ) t
WHERE t.EMP_CODE='A';
```